# Add Area 51 to the Stack Exchange dropdown

Tags: feature-request, area-51, stack-exchange, header

I love the new Stack Exchange dropdown in the header. But what about Area 51? Did it get abducted by aliens?

[image]

Comment: Regarding the close vote for "can no longer be reproduced": it can still be reproduced via the dropdown in the upper right.

Comment: @RyanM The close vote is valid in this case. Area 51 was later added when the top bar was redesigned in 2013. The fact that it's not there today is an [entirely new bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353231/why-is-the-area-51-site-no-longer-showing-up-on-the-more-stack-exchange-communit).

Answer (score 4):

It's [Area 51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_51), man! It can't be found!

[image]
<sub>(source: [howstuffworks.com](https://static.howstuffworks.com/gif/area-51-1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: It can be found, just not entered.

Comment: I want to believe!

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that Area 51 isn't like the other Stack Exchange sites. Try running some Stack Overflow [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) scripts on Area 51 to see what I mean. All the ones (reputation gain tracker for example) I've tried don't work there, but work on the other sites. That's probably where part of the problem is.

Comment: comment threading, the comment reply button and the "revision" link work fine for me...

Comment: There are three different API's on StackExchange, (correct if there is a mistake) Stack Overflow, StackExchange and Area 51. Area 51 does not have an actual Q/A structure. It is a proposal/action area.