# Why isn't Area 51 listed in "Site Directory"?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, area-51, stack-exchange

The always interesting [Site Directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites) does not list [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), why is this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65568/add-area51-to-the-stackexchange-dropdown/65635#65635

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Area 51 isn't a Q&A site like the rest, so it doesn't belong in the list of "network sites".

We did, however, just add links to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), and [the blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) to the sidebar of the [Site Directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page, so those sites should be slightly more discoverable now.

Answer (score 2):

Because Area 51 technically does not exist.