# Why does my reputation browser not show Area 51, even though my flair does?

Tags: discussion, reputation, stackexchange.com

For example, my [network flair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPhEK.png) has icons for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350209/cole-johnson), [Meta Stack Overflow](https://web.archive.org/web/20130806171001/http://meta.stackoverflow.com:80/users/186285/cole-johnson), [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/130931/cole-johnson), Mathematics and [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/58591/cole-johnson), but my [reputation browser](https://stackexchange.com/users/1426955/cole-johnson?tab=reputation) only shows the first four of those (i.e. not Area 51). Why?

[image: My badge]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](http://www.stackexchange.com/users/flair/1426955.png))</sub>

Comment: It is because Jeff enjoys your suffering.

Comment: I half feel like this is supposed to have a `[tag:jeff]` since you seem to be asking him directly. You might have to wait 6-8 weeks for a response...

Comment: Possibly related answer (by Jeff) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65635/172936

Comment: In the past when I put either of the two co-founders names directly I got burnt everytime. Guessing their answer would be along the lines that Area 51 is a birthplace for Q & A sites and not a Q & A site **for rep purposes**. Again guessing but I sense this is where the [PreCog](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive) badge might bridge the gap. My 2 cents.

Comment: I see it on your reputation browser, maybe you lack top-secret security clearance?