# Why is the Area 51 site no longer showing up on the More Stack Exchange Communities list?

Tags: support, bug, area-51, communities-list

**Why is the Area 51 site no longer showing up on the More Stack Exchange Communities list?**

Prior to today, the More Stack Exchange Communities list in the top bar contained a link to Area 51.

However, when I hit the link to the Stack Exchange Communities on the top right corner of my screen, I have noticed that the Area 51 community link is missing now.

Why is this so? Is it due to a bug in the system, or is it intentional that it was removed? Perhaps a new series of protocols are in place that I am unaware of?

This has just recently happened. After all **Area 51** is a **Stack Exchange Community**! Is there any official explanation for this?

Comment: It is showing for me on the list I edited.

Comment: @rene It is still absent on mine.

Comment: This is what I am seeing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KplO.png

Comment: @rene the OP means (I presume) the More Stack Exchange Communities list, below the customizable list.

Comment: Very slightly related: *[How can I get URLs and site names for a cross-site SEDE query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359794)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Area 51 to the Stack Exchange dropdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65568/add-area-51-to-the-stack-exchange-dropdown)

Comment: @MartinSchröder The question says "This has recently happened" and you posted a link to a question from 10 years earlier. It definitely does not answer the user's question.